# Conditionally turn on/off DataAnnotation property validation

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I'm new to Validation using DataAnnotations. I'm using this in a console application, so not ASP/MVC, etc.

```
public class Phone
{
   [Required]
   public string Mobile { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string Office { get; set; }
}

public class Physician
{
    [Required]
    public Phone ContactPhone { get; set; }
}

public class Patient
{
    [Required]
    public Phone ContactPhone { get; set; }
}
```

Now, consider for a Physician object, Mobile and Office are required, however for the Patient object only Mobile is required. How can I turn on/off validation attribute behavior based on a given condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `Physician` and `Patient` classes need to decide what is and is not required inside of the `Phone` class. We can do that by avoiding annotations in the first place and instead use the `IValidatableObject` interface. The `Validator` class will also check this interface for any additional validation.

```
public class Phone
{
    // no more required attributes here
    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    public string Office { get; set; }
}

public class Physician : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public Phone ContactPhone { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactPhone.Mobile))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Mobile number is required");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactPhone.Office))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Office number is required");
        }
    }
}

public class Patient : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public Phone ContactPhone { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ContactPhone.Mobile))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Mobile number is required");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense.